# OpenFileDialog forces SkyDrive Documents path

Tags: openfiledialog, onedrive

In my .Net 4.5 C# application, I pass Documents folder path like "C:\Users\[UserName]\Documents" to OpenFileDialog.InitialDirectory but for some reason that I can't figure out it opens "C:\Users\[UserName\\SkyDrive\Documents". I can't find anyway to force it to open my default Documents folder which is "C:\Users\[UserName]\Documents"! I am logged in to my Windows 8.1 with my Hotmail account if that helps. Is there anyway I can force OpenFileDialog to open the path I am asking for instead of OS choose it for me?

Answer (score 0):

I've just come across this problem myself.

It appears there's a property called `AutoUpgradeEnabled` that's `true` by default. If you set it to `false`, it restores the older behaviour, although it also restores the older appearance.

There's a page about it here:

http://www.thomasclaudiushuber.com/blog/2008/04/12/vistas-savefiledialog-and-openfiledialog-in-wpf/

Comment: I actually want to keep the new appearance. My problem is how to force it to always open default Documents folder instead of Skype documents folder. Before Skype was added this was working fine. Thanks anyway.